# NATS request-reply with multitenancy

Tags: nats.io

I am using NATS request-reply fine but I am planning to add multitenancy with accounts. Do I need extra configuration for the `replyTo` inbox? For example

Tenant A:
listens on `rpc.method`. This subject is exported as a service to Tenant B.

Tenant B:
initiates a req-reply to `rpc.method` specifying a replyChannel. Usually this looks like _INBOX.xxxxx.

So, when a subscriber that lives in Tenant A wants to send the response back, will the requestor in Tenant B receive it, given that _INBOX.xxxxx is not exported to Tenant B

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Allow Responses](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/authorization#allow-responses-map) feature works with multitenancy. NATS will dynamically present client's (Tenant B) reply subject to the service account (Tenant A) as a dynamic subject local to Tenant A that the service can publish response to for a period of time.

Comment: Thanks @tbeets! I've validated the setup and described it in the post below due to comment-lenght limitation.
I've noticed the new dynamic `_R_.>` replyTo subject you mentioned. However, I am not finding any references to it in the docs. Is this here to stay? It's an important questions since the replier must be authorized to publish to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @tbeets!.

I created a simple setup to test the full setup. Imagine two accounts `server` and `client` and an exported service called `rpc`.

Here is what happens:

The client imports the `rpc` service and does the usual req-rep. It advertises a regular `_INBOX.xxx` replyTo subject.

However the `server`, being a different account/tenant, receives the message with the replyTo overwritten to `_R_.yyyy`. The `server` replies to `_R_.yyy` but the `client` still receives its response on the original topic _IBOX.xxx.

That's pretty slick!

The only change needed is to let the server publish to `_R_.>` (`--allow-pub '_R_.>'`)